# How to get the input data of a field from my webapp

Tags: javascript, spring, web-applications

I am trying to create an app for house rental, and i dont know how to get the user's input data (e.g: size,price etc). Is there anyone that can help or suggest any solution ?

My github links:

Frontend:
https://github.com/Gkonst1/chatbotEstateAgent

Backend:
https://github.com/loukia12/backend-CB

Comment: Not enough information. Which framework are you using? Can you show some code. if you want information on backend from your webapp, you have to implement rest API.

Comment: @Tanmay_vijay i am using react for the frontend and spring for backend. i can add the github links for back and front if you want to.

Comment: So to be clear you want to send data from react app to spring boot application?

Comment: Well, i have my webapp and i want to take the values that user is using to search for houses so i can return the results for these values @Tanmay_vijay